# How do I proceed with my Econometrics project ?? Would appreciate any suggestions

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, panel-data

I am doing an Econometrics Project  where i have to show whether  there is any relationship between GDP growth rate and Labour, ICT capital, Non-ICT capital and Multifactor productivity. The data is on 10 countries dated from 2000-2014.

1) The first problem I have is that the data given to me on these four explanatory variables is measured in percentage point contribution to GDP. I find this weird as if the data itself shows the relationship between GDP growth and these variables, what am I supposed to show?

2) This topic seems to be related to Neo-Classical Economics model of growth which shows that how GDP growth can be separated into growth in labour, capital and productivity. This is what given in the data where the sum of the percentage point contributions of above 4 explanatory variables approximately equals GDP growth rate in every year. What I fail to understand is what then happens to influence of variables like Consumption, Inflation, Govt debt among others on GDP growth rate. Don't these affect the GDP growth rate at all?

I would really appreciate any leads here.

Comment: "How do I proceed with my project?" is too broad. Please edit to have specific questions - including your title. (Please also try to keep your questions specifically on statistical issues rather than economic ones.)

Answer (score 1):

(1) That is interesting. Look, you will know what your professor is looking for better than me, but if you want to be impressive, try estimating an autoregressive model of GDP growth rate for each country using the data. How you will do this is your call. There are plenty of ML techniques that may work, but you are the one with the data. If you can reduce the residuals to white noise, than you have something.

(2) This is more of an economics question than one of ML, but I will answer it anyway. The question you are dealing with has to do with GDP **growth rate**. This means that you are dealing with shifts in long-run aggregate supply and the PPC curve, not temporary shifts in aggregate demand. Consumption influences aggregate demand, and so does government spending, both directly and indirectly through the market for loanable funds (interest rate).

Economic growth is long term. It means that the potential GDP of the economy is increasing. This only happens when there are large-scale improvements to the economy: Productivity growth, increases in quantity/quality of economic resources, etc.